# Email Development - HTML

Tags: css, outlook, position, html-email, email-client

I rarely do Email HTML, however I am currently trying to make a sample email using HTML, CSS - the issue I have though, is that when I test it on Outlook online, "a's" are appearing everywhere and I aren't sure why? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

```
  <style media="screen">

  </style>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#efe1b0">
<!-- Full container for page -->
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#efe1b0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!-- Main email container -->
        <table class="container" width="640" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

          <!-- Row 1 (Logo) -->
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="logo" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 10px 20px 0px 30px; border-left: 1px solid #dbc064; border-right: 1px solid #dbc064; border-top: 1px solid #dbc064;">
              <img style="margin-left: -10px;" src="images/large_logo.gif" alt="Our Vineyard" width="585" height="45" border="0">
            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- Row 2 (Headline)-->
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="headline" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 15px 20px 5px 30px; border-left: 1px solid #dbc064; border-right: 1px solid #dbc064; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px;">
              <h1 style="margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 32px; color: #723c7f;">Main Heading Here</h1>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- Row 3 (Image Banner) -->
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" bgcolor="#f5f2e5" class="banner" style="border-left: 1px solid #dbc064; border-right: 1px solid #dbc064;">
              <img src="images/banner_large.jpg" width="638" height="180" alt="Photo of Our Vineyard" />
            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- Row 4 -->
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" bgcolor="#f5f2e5" class="content" style="padding: 30px 30px 10px 30px; border-left: 1px solid #dbc064; border-right: 1px solid #dbc064; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; color: #654308;">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam commodo justo tellus, non fringilla dolor scelerisque vel. Nam hendrerit eros quis elementum gravida. Cras faucibus accumsan erat at pellentesque. Etiam a ultricies enim, eget lacinia sem. Integer et elit orci. Morbi ac mauris sapien. Suspendisse viverra pellentesque orci, imperdiet posuere erat aliquam eu.
              <br><br>Enjoy,<br>
              <img src="images/josh.gif" width="90" height="40" alt="Joshua" />
            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- Row 5 -->
          <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- Row 6 -->
          <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
          </tr>

          <!-- Row 7 -->
          <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Paste the code you are using so we can see it.

Comment: Do html as if you are back in the 90s - tables, tables, tables! but not too many nested! A good guide: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/

Comment: @David Done, thanks.

Comment: @arkascha I know, it's horrendous! But I want it to display correctly in all clients! If possible!

Comment: If you copy and paste your code into notepad, are there any special characters in those places?  Looks like there may be blank characters that can't be interpreted so they are being changed to an a

Comment: As a test, try removing the white space in your code. I used to see this when pasting in text and it would mess with the character coding / spacing

Comment: @Pete Nope, it is coming up just fine. Could it be because I have used padding? Or maybe because I have not specified a document type? Though it works in W10 email client fine...

Comment: Ah yeah, you probably need the doc type.  Outlook is a very basic browser - think ie5.5!

Comment: @David The white space removal fixed it! Thank you very much for everyone's help!

Comment: Aha, super. Onwards you march.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give reference to my comment, close up your table rows, IE:

```
<tr>
        <td valign="top" class="logo" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 10px 20px 0px 30px; border-left: 1px solid #dbc064; border-right: 1px solid #dbc064; border-top: 1px solid #dbc064;">
          <img style="margin-left: -10px;" src="images/large_logo.gif" alt="Our Vineyard" width="585" height="45" border="0">
        </td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td valign="top" class="headline" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 15px 20px 5px 30px; border-left: 1px solid #dbc064; border-right: 1px solid #dbc064; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px;">
          <h1 style="margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 32px; color: #723c7f;">Main Heading Here</h1>
        </td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#f5f2e5" class="banner" style="border-left: 1px solid #dbc064; border-right: 1px solid #dbc064;">
          <img src="images/banner_large.jpg" width="638" height="180" alt="Photo of Our Vineyard" />
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, 
1) Avoid using margins and paddings. Use td's to create vertical spacing. See below

```
<td width="20">&nbps;</td>
```

2) Use tr's to create horizontal spacing between sections.

```
<tr><td style="line-height: 10px; font-size: 10px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```